# How to place calls with IVR with S4B

Tags: skype-for-business, ivr

I need to build a PoC where I can **automate the process of calling people**, putting a **IVR** with two option, and then register that option again in the database.

I need this to be able to make several calls at the same time (about 10).

Is this posible? So far (Im new with this), I've just found how to answer calls and do the IVR process, but I need to place calls. For example, this is seems to be what I need, but it's for answering, not placing calls:
[See Post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205321.aspx#Creating%20or%20modifying%20an%20interactive%20workflow)

BTW, this is for external numbers, phone numbers, not just S4B users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do outbound calls without a person dialing it, at least at a native S4B layer. See here the one community specialist [answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/SkypeforBusiness/message-id/1188#M1190).